# Requiring files in electron without babel

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to convert a web application into an electron app. I have multiple functions, in different files that I've imported into my main.js using a transpiler.

However, whenever I try do that in my electron app, I run into an issue with a module I'm using to move away from using php to access my database. Instead I'm using the mysql module on npm.

I want to save this function in its own file, and then require it in main.js. When I try to transpile it with babel, I get an error about Net.Connection not working (or something along those lines). As I understand it, this is because of how Node works. I'm happy to work around this, but I'm hoping there's a way to save this function in another file, and import it without having to use babel.

```
function loadColourFilter(){
  var mysql      = require('mysql');
  let query_result;

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    user     : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    password : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  connection.connect();
  let query = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {

  });

  connection.end();
  return (query_result);

}
```

EDIT: I've removed some parts of the function to keep credentials safe and whatnot. I'm fairly certain their absence won't change anything when trying to solve this.

EDIT:
My project directory is essentially

```
src
--- js
--- --- main.js
    --- functionFile.js // This would be where my loadColourFilter function above would be saved
--- node_modules
--- --- ...
--- index.html // js/main.js is referenced in a script tag here.
--- main.js // Where the electron window is created.
--- package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be 2 js contexts, one running in the electron app and one running in node. You won't be able to require you scripts directly from your directory if you are in the electron context (which is like a browser js context).

I'm just assuming this is the case since we don't get a lot of information for your problem, and the other answer should have resolved your problem.

Try to include your js file in your index.html and see what's up.

Edit: Since it's a Transpiling error with babel, babel is probably transpiling for node when it should transpile for the browser.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying about the two different contexts, but I could use some help differentiating them in my project.

I've edited my initial question to include my project directory

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a simple local module using NodeJS by creating a source file and then adding a module.exports assignment to export some functionality/variables/etc from the file. In your case something like a file named colourFilter.js with the contents:

```
function load(){
  var mysql      = require('mysql');
  let query_result;

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    user     : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    password : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  connection.connect();
  let query = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {

  });

  connection.end();
  return (query_result);

}

module.exports = load
```

And then in your code where you'd like to use it include it by doing something like:

```
loadColourFilter = require('colourFilter.js')
```

And use the function like

```
let result = loadColourFilter()
```

This is a simple way to split up your code into multiple files/classes/modules but still keep one main file/class/module as the important one which is the public-facing portion or entry point. And of course you don't have to use the names I've used above :P

If you would like to make an object-style module you can instead export an object like

```
module.exports = {
  load
}
```

Or

```
module.exports = {
  load: loadFunctionNameInThisFile
}
```

And then use it like

```
const colourFilter = require('colourFilter.js')

let result = colourFilter.load()
```

Comment: The issue is, when I try to do something like this, I get the error "Cannot find module 'colourFilter.js'"

I've tried adding the path in the require like colourFilter = require('./colourFilter.js') as well, and no luck.

Comment: Sorry. That path may be the issue because `./` points to a file in the current directory. If it is in a folder above the main script you can use `..`, for example if the main script is in `project/src/` and the module is in `project/` you can use `./../module.js`. If it is in a folder below the current directory, for example if the main script is in `project/src/` and the module is in `project/src/lib` you can use `./lib/module.js`.

If this continues to fail please share your Node + NPM versions & edit in the sanitized module source (or at least basics of it) above.

Comment: All my scripts are stored in the same directory. So I would have js/main.js and then js/colourFilter.js and still no luck.

Comment: Interesting. I tested just now with a very basic Electron app that only has Electron + mysql as dependencies with the code in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/l3l_aze/4cqmhgbt/) (multiple files in the JS section split up by comments) and there are no issues running it. Have you tried skipping Babel (if possible), or making it skip that file?

Also found that I was wrong above because the single export style only exports a function directly and it is imported to whatever you call it rather than as an object. Edited my answer to correct that; I'm sorry for the misinformation.